# Set an externally accessible URL for a React component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, url

I developed a React component representing a window that allows the user to interact with a chatbot. This window opens when the user clicks a button. Now, I want to make this button available in any site or application of my choice. The first idea that came to mind is to associate a URL to this button so I can call it in our site or application by simply creating a link like:

```
<a href= "url of the button that opens the chatbot window"> Chat with the robot </a>.
```

I find the idea functional but I do not know how to associate a URL to a component in React. I looked at the React-Router side of what I understood it just allows to create the navigation between component of the same application but I do not know if its URL can be accessible outside the application where they are created.

Do you know any tips for solving such problems?
And if you have ideas other than linking the URL to the component, I'm interested.

Thank you in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a react component by pulling it in as external code. react-router works by wrapping you application. Any component you want to use has to be part of the actual codebase.